# Make check IsUserLoggedIn in react native after getting data from Rest Api using Async Storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the data of Logged In User using Rest `Api` and i am storing that data in `Async Storage`. Now i want to make checks in `App.js` file to Restrict User if it is already logged in go to home screen directly and if user is `loggedOut` go to Welcome screen/ Sign In screen first.

Here is My code Where i am getting the data from server and storing in the `async storage`.

```
axios.post('api/v1/user/do_login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
          })
          .then( async (response) => {
            if(response.data.type == "success"){
               alert("Login Successfully");
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('full_name', response.data.profile.pmeta.full_name);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('user_type', response.data.profile.pmeta.user_type);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('profile_img', response.data.profile.pmeta.profile_img);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('profileType', response.data.type);

              this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

            }else if(response.data.type == "error"){
              alert("Incorrect Detail");
            }
        })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

And Here i am getting the data in App.js and setting Name ,  Profile Image and etc in Custom Drawer Layout.

```
state={
    storedValue:'',
    storedType:'',
    profileImg:'',
    type:'',
    showAlert: false 
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getUser();
  }
  getUser = async() =>{

    try {
      const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('full_name');
      const storedType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
      const profileImg= await AsyncStorage.getItem('profile_img');
      const type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profileType');
      console.log(storedValue ,storedType, profileImg  ,type);
      if(storedValue !== null){
         this.setState({storedValue})
      }else{
        // alert('something wrong')
      }


      if(storedType !== null){
        this.setState({storedType})
     }else{
      //  alert('something wrong')
     }

     if(profileImg !== null){
      this.setState({profileImg})
   }else{
    //  alert('something wrong')
   }

   if(type !== null){
    this.setState({type})
 }else{
  //  alert('something wrong')
 }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
      // alert(error)

    }

  }


<View style={{height:150 , backgroundColor:'#fafafa' , flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <Image
       source={{uri: `${profileImg}`}} style={{ marginLeft:20 , marginTop:65, height:60 , width:60 , borderRadius:50}}/>
      <View style={{marginLeft:10 , marginTop:75,flexDirection:'column'}}>
      { storedValue != "" ?
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'500' }}>{storedValue}</Text> :
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'500' }}>Guest</Text> 
      }

      {storedType != "" ?
        <Text>{storedType}</Text>:
        <Text>Greeting</Text>}

      </View>
```

Above code is Working but i want to add checks and i am not understanding how to make checks in React native on the bases of logged in User.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have get state from redux or context api

```
 const isLoggedIn = this.props.store.isLogin;

const Layout = createRootNavigator(isLoggedIn);
return <Layout />;
```

here is the createRootNavigator

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainNavigatior from './MainNavigator';
import GuestNavigator from './GuestNavigator';

const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => createSwitchNavigator(
{
SignedIn: {
  screen: MainNavigatior, //home 
},
SignedOut: {
  screen: GuestNavigator, //login & signup
},
},
 {
initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'SignedIn' : 'SignedOut',
 },
);

 export default createRootNavigator;
```

in app js I hava check if user exist in async storage and update state

```
async componentWillMount() {
await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER').then((user) => {
  this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(user) || {} });

    if (user) {
    this.props.setStatus({ isLogin: true });
    }
  });
  }
```

Comment: Should i Use this code in my App.js to handle routes?

Comment: what are you storing in isLoggedIn  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly navigate to your home screen or login screen from the `app.js` class using switch navigator.

eg:

> App.js

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
...
...

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
  },
  { headerMode: "none" }
);
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
  },
  { headerMode: "none" }
);

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    PreLoader: PreLoader,
    Home: HomeStack,
    Login: LoginStack,
  },
  { headerMode: "none", initialRouteName: "PreLoader" }
);

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default App;
```

> PreLoader.js

```
...

//Method to check whether user logged in or not.
_checkUserLoginStatus= async() =>{
try {
  const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('full_name');
  const storedType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
  const profileImg= await AsyncStorage.getItem('profile_img');
  const type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profileType');
  console.log(storedValue ,storedType, profileImg  ,type);
  if(storedValue !== null){
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
  }else{
     this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
  }

} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
  // alert(error)
   this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
}
```

...